# AWS step function: Adding States.Format output to input at top level

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

The step function receives some input and looks up a bunch more and after that I want to add the result of a States.Format function to that input at the top level.  I don't know all the input when the States.Format function is run so I need to keep all that input.  Also the result of the States.Format function has to be at the top level - not in a sub-object.

If I use the Pass state to add the States.Format output then

- Result only allows literal strings so that won't work:

  ```
    Prepare Interaction:
      Type: Pass
      Result: States.Format('payment/receipt of {} made today', $.receiptValue)
      ResultPath: $.interactionText
      Next: Create Interaction
  ```

  when passed:

  ```
    { ..., ReceiptValue: 123, ... }
  ```

  produces:

  ```
    { ..., ReceiptValue: 123, ..., interactionText: "States.Format('payment/receipt of {} made today', $.receiptValue)" }
  ```
- Parameters creates a key-value pair and ResultPath requires a separate key so the result is not at the top level:

  ```
    Prepare Interaction:
      Type: Pass
      Parameters:
        interactionText.$: States.Format('payment/receipt of {} made today', $.receiptValue)
      ResultPath: $.interactionText
      Next: Create Interaction
  ```

  when passed:

  ```
    { ..., ReceiptValue: 123, ... }
  ```

  produces:

  ```
    { ..., ReceiptValue: 123, ..., interactionText: { interactionText: "payment/receipt of 123 made today" }}
  ```
- Even if you grab all the input with Parameters there is no way to add an item to it:

  ```
    Prepare Interaction:
      Type: Pass
      Parameters:
        Payload.$: $
        Payload.interactionText.$: States.Format('payment/receipt of {} made today', $.receiptValue)
      OutputPath: $.Payload
      Next: Create Interaction
  ```

  when passed:

  ```
    { ..., ReceiptValue: 123, ... }
  ```

  produces:

  ```
    { ..., ReceiptValue: 123, ..., "Payload.interactionText": "payment/receipt of 123 made today" }
  ```

There is no way to remove the key from Parameters and just using `ResultPath: $` doesn't keep the input.  Is there any way to get a step function to produce

```
{ ..., ReceiptValue: 123, ..., interactionText: "payment/receipt of 123 made today" }
```

either using a Pass state or some other method that doesn't call a lambda?

Here is the entire step function:

```
  StateMachine:
    definition:
      StartAt: Retrieve Customer Profile
      States:
        Retrieve Customer Profile:
          Type: Task
          Resource: arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke
          OutputPath: $.Payload
          Parameters:
            Payload.$: $
            FunctionName: !GetAtt RetrieveCustomerProfile.Arn
          Next: Prepare Interaction
        Prepare Interaction:
          Type: Pass
          OutputPath: $.Payload
          Parameters:
            Payload.$: $
            Payload.interactionText.$: States.Format('payment/receipt of {} made today by {}', $.receiptValue, $.phoneNumber)
          Next: Create Interaction
        Create Interaction:
          Type: Task
          Resource: arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke
          OutputPath: $.Payload
          Parameters:
            Payload.$: $
            FunctionName: !GetAtt CreateInteraction.Arn
          Next: End
        End:
          Type: Succeed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use the [States.JsonMerge intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-json-manipulate) for this. The example below shows how to this with a series of Pass States.

```
{
  "Comment": "An example to demonstrate merging keys into a single object",
  "StartAt": "Simulate Function Output",
  "States": {
    "Simulate Function Output": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": {
        "receiptValue": 25,
        "otherValue1": "some string",
        "otherValue2": "some other string"
      },
      "Next": "Augment"
    },
    "Augment": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "origional.$": "$",
        "new": {
          "interactionText.$": "States.Format('payment/receipt of {} made today', $.receiptValue)"
        }
      },
      "Next": "Merge"
    },
    "Merge": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "End": true,
      "Parameters": {
        "merged.$": "States.JsonMerge($.origional, $.new, false)"
      },
      "OutputPath": "$.merged"
    }
  }
}
```

For your specific example though, you shouldn't need to have any Pass states. Imagine you have a function called `myFirstFunction` that returns this as a response. Then you want to pass the merged object to `mySecondFunction`.

```
{
  "receiptValue": 25,
  "otherValue1": "some string",
  "otherValue2": "some other string"
}
```

This is how you could do it without needing a Pass state.

```
{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "Lambda Function 1",
  "States": {
    "Lambda Function 1": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": "$",
        "FunctionName": "myFirstFunction"
      },
      "ResultSelector": {
        "raw.$": "$.Payload",
        "extra": {
          "interactionText.$": "States.Format('payment/receipt of {} made today', $.Payload.receiptValue)"
        }
      },
      "Next": "Lambda Function 2"
    },
    "Lambda Function 2": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": "States.JsonMerge($.raw, $.extra, false)",
        "FunctionName": "mySecondFunction"
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

You will see that I use ResultSelector to do the augmentation before returning the result from the first Lambda function. Then I use States.JsonMerge to merge before sending to the second function.

The second function will then get the following, which I think is what you wanted:

```
{
  "receiptValue": 25,
  "otherValue2": "some other string",
  "otherValue1": "some string",
  "interactionText": "payment/receipt of 25 made today"
}
```